# Скроллер на верх

Tags: html, прокрутка, css, javascript

Помогите на этом примере сделать плавный скроллер на вверх!

```
<style>
.wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 50px;
}

.mini {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid #333333;
    background: #eee;
    overflow: auto;
}
</style>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="mini">
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <a href="#top">Наверх</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На чистом JS (http://jsfiddle.net/QvE97/1/):

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="mini" id="mini">
    ...
    </div>
</div>

function scrollTo(element, to, duration) {
    if(typeof element == 'String')
        element = document.getElementById(element);
    if (duration < 0) return;
    var difference = to - element.scrollTop;
    var perTick = difference / duration * 10;

    setTimeout(function() {
        element.scrollTop = element.scrollTop + perTick;
        scrollTo(element, to, duration - 10);
    }, 10);
}

var lnk = document.getElementById('lnkToTop');
var mini = document.getElementById('mini');
lnk.onclick = function() {
    scrollTo(mini, 0, 300)
}
```

С JQuery (http://jsfiddle.net/QvE97/):

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="mini" id="mini">
    ...
    </div>
</div>

$(function() {
    $('#lnkToTop').click(function()
    {
        $('.mini').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 300);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: не за что :)